# document.getElementById não funciona no Firefox e Edge

Tags: javascript

**Tenho 1 pagina onde carrego todas as páginas dentro de uma  `<div content>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

    <script>
        var vars = geturlvar()['Nome'];
        $(function () {
            $("#includedContent").load(vars);
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        function CarregaCamposModulo() {
            debugger;
            var id = localStorage.id;
            var nome = localStorage.nome;
            document.getElementById("id_id").value = id;
            document.getElementById("id_nome").value = nome;
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body class="theme-red" onload="CarregaModulos();CarregaCamposModulo()">
    <section class="content">
        <img src="../images/carregando.gif" id="image">
        <div id="includedContent"></div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

**E a página que carrego dentro do `includedContent` pelo link `http://localhost/i9maker/pages/container_admin.html?Nome=consultas/admin_modulo.html` **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Módulos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-left: -29px; margin-right: -29px">
        <!--Striped Rows-->
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="card-panel" style="margin-top: -29px; ">
                    <div class="card" style="background: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.6)">
                        <div class="body">
                            <form class="form" id="wizard_with_validation" method="POST">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                        <input id="id_id" name="id_id" type="hidden" class="form-control input-style" autofocus required>
                                        <label class="label-margin-top">Descrição*</label>
                                        <input id="id_nome" name="id_nome" type="text" class="form-control input-style input-casesensitive" autofocus required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Está funcionando no Google Chrome, porém no Firefox e Edge, não funciona, o erro se da na hora do:**

> document.getElementById("id_id").value = id;
>
> document.getElementById("id_nome").value = descricao;

**Depurando no Edge aparece o erro:**

> Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Imagem no firefox, funciona apenas no modo debug, se executo sem o modo debug não traz nada.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Google Chrome, essa é no Google Chrome:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: console.log(`localStorage.id`) dá qual resultado?

Comment: @Marconi  o resultado é 1

Comment: Fiz um [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzzd9brj/) não consegui reproduzir o problema pelo ao menos no Firefox.

Comment: @Marconi  editei a pergunta e acrescentei mais detalhes de como estou fazendo, tem mais alguns detalhes que não pensei que não teriam importancia, pois estou fazendo um include dessa página em outra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema:
1) Coloquei o formulário de cadastro no mesmo lugar do formulário de consulta, deixando visível ou invisível quando preciso. 
Pesquisando mais a fundo, vi várias pessoas relatando problema similares com `document.getElementById`, segundo elas, apesar da função `onload` carregar todos os dados do formulário antes de executar a função, [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp), em certas circunstâncias ele executa antes. Bem, não sei se é isso, só sei que colocando na mesma página funcionou blz. 
Como estou utilizando o mesmo projeto no **CORDOVA**, não poderia optar por uma linguagem server-side como **PHP** ou **ASPX.**
Agradeço a disponibilidade e tempo gasto por Marconi e Guilherme.

Comment: é porque vc só postou na pergunta a parte do `admin_modulo.html`, tinha que ter postado o `container_admin.html`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, tem razão foi vacilo meu, mas a solução ficou até melhor do que fazer em páginas diferentes, por não coloquei o resto do código como você pediu. Mas valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: Esse é o problema, eu ia estava para editar, você esta embutindo um HTML dentro o que deve estar causando um baita de um efeito colateral

Comment: @Guilherme, depois das suas dicas, retirei todos os scripts de dentro da página container_admin.html e coloquei dentro de arquivos `.js`  e deixei na página `admin_modulo.html` só o necessário. depois disso as mensagens de alerta desapareceram.

Comment: Sim, ainda sim a estrutura includa é falha, claro que é outro problema, assim que conseguir explico com mais detalhes.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, agradeço amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Geralmente `id=""` e `name=""` devem ser iguais, alguns comportamentos (ao menos nos IEs antigos) causava problemas, ainda sim recomendo colocar dentro de um `window.onload` ou dentro de algo como `DOMContentloaded`, por exemplo:

```
function CarregaCamposModulo() {
    debugger;
    var id = localStorage.id;
    var descricao = localStorage.descricao;
    alert(id);
    alert(descricao);
    document.getElementById("id_id").value = id;
    document.getElementById("id_nome").value = descricao;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    CarregaCamposModulo();
});
```

**Outra coisa** que pode ocasionar o problema é o comportamento de `name` e `id` em diferentes navegadores, recomendo que o `name` e o `id` sempre sejam o mesmo, troque isto:

```
<input id="id_id" name="id" type="text" class="form-control input-style" autofocus required>
```

Por isto:

```
<input id="id_id" name="id_id" type="text" class="form-control input-style" autofocus required>
```

E ajuste no teu back-end e outros scripts para usarem `id_id`.